# css link tags becoming style tags onload?

Tags: jquery, css

I've just noticed a peculiarity when inspecting the head section using chrome dev tools (and firebug) that link tags are mysteriously becoming style tags, with the href attribute also changing into data-href.

HTML source...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="main.css" />
```

Soon becomes...

```
▶<style media="screen, projection" data-href="main.css">...</style>
```

Is this new? What's going on here?

And, can we hook into it (jquery), is this an event firing off that can be manipulated?

Comment: I"m guessing here, but this sounds native, I doubt you'll be able to attach any sort of handler. What are you after exactly?

Comment: I want truth/understanding for its own sake.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a pretty old question, but they probably where using [prefixfree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) or some similar library.